# How to add only values from another list to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to add values from *mean_test_score* to an existing dictionary. The existing dictionary looks like this:

```
data= [{'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'rbf',},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'linear'},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'rbf'},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'linear'},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'linear'},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}]
```

My key is constant. It is a string called *mean_test_score*. My *mean_test_score* looks like this:

```
mean_test_score= {0.92173913, 0.60434783, 0.92173913, 0.60496894, 0.92173913,
       0.71863354, 0.92173913, 0.70993789, 0.92732919, 0.67298137,
       0.92732919, 0.72515528, 0.92732919, 0.78074534, 0.92732919,
       0.73664596, 0.92484472, 0.68478261, 0.92484472, 0.73726708,
       0.92484472, 0.85776398, 0.92484472, 0.83975155, 0.91273292,
       0.68478261, 0.91273292, 0.73571429, 0.91273292, 0.87670807,
       0.91273292, 0.88167702, 0.91024845, 0.68478261, 0.91024845,
       0.73540373, 0.91024845, 0.88074534, 0.91024845, 0.89161491}
```

So after the kernel in the dictionary *data* I would like to add the `key = 'mean_test_score'` and value which should iterate through the m*ean_test_score* and be added. I have tried a few solutions but they did not work.

The desired output is

```
data= [{'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'linear','mean_test_score': 0.92173913 },
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'rbf','mean_test_score': 0.60434783},
       {'C': 0.1, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'linear', 'mean_test_score': 0.92173913},
       and so on ]
```

Comment: Show an example of the desired output !

Comment: What did you try, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `mean_test_score` is a list rather than a dictionary as mentioned in your question.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
mean_test_score = list(mean_test_score)
count = 0
for i in data:
    i['mean_test_score'] = mean_test_score[count]
    count += 1
```

Comment: it gives the following error: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @CD_NS can you edit your `mean_test_score` in the question. Is it a list?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was trying in a wrong cell in jupyter. Many thanks, @sid.

Answer (score 2):

```
for d, m in zip(data, mean_test_score):
    d['mean_test_score'] = m
```